# calling methods and adjusting button text

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a meal scheduler in conjunction with PyQt5 and Qt Designer (eventually this will produce a shopping list from a database). The meal schedule is a grid of 7 x 3 buttons (7 days and 3 meals per day) - 21 buttons in total.

When a user clicks a button in the meal schedule (one of the "SelMealButtons"), a pop up window opens with a list of meals to chose from (this is the Selector class in the code). The user selects a meal and confirms their selection with an "OK" button (the "pushButton" in the code that follows).

I'm trying to get the meal name to appear as the corresponding button text back in the meal schedule via the "set_button_labels" method. For simplicity there are only three of the 21 "SelMealButtons" referenced in the example code, which is as follows:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

uifile_1 = 'untitled3.ui'
form_1, base_1 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_1)

uifile_2 = 'untitled2.ui'
form_2, base_2 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_2)

array = ["Meal 1", "Meal 2", "Meal 3"]
meal_schedule = [""]*21

class Schedule(base_1, form_1):

    def __init__(self):
        super(base_1,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.SelMealButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.m_b_pressed(0))
        self.SelMealButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.m_b_pressed(1))
        self.SelMealButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.m_b_pressed(2))

    def m_b_pressed(self, button_no):
        self.selector = Selector()
        self.selector.show()
        self.selector.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.selector.OKbutton(button_no))

    def set_button_labels(self, message):
        print(message)
        self.SelMealButton.setText(meal_schedule[0])
        self.SelMealButton_2.setText(meal_schedule[1])
        self.SelMealButton_3.setText(meal_schedule[2])

class Selector(base_2, form_2):

    def __init__(self):
        super(base_2, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        for item in array:
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.closewindow)

    def closewindow(self):
        self.close()
        self.schedule = Schedule()

    def OKbutton(self, button_no):
         x = self.listWidget.currentRow()
         y = str(array[x])
         meal_schedule[button_no] = y
         self.schedule = Schedule()
         self.schedule.set_button_labels(y)
         self.close()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     s = Schedule()
     s.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The UI files are as follows:

**untitled3.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>234</width>
    <height>339</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="SelMealButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="MealtimeLabel">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>51</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Breakfast</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>21</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Mon</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="SelMealButton_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>120</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="SelMealButton_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>180</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>140</y>
      <width>47</width>
      <height>13</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Lunch</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>200</y>
      <width>47</width>
      <height>13</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Dinner</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>234</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

And **untitled2.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>256</width>
     <height>281</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>290</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>OK</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>290</x>
     <y>60</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Cancel</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

This works so far as when the "OKbutton" method is called from the "Selector" class, it assigns the listWidget value to the meal_schedule array. I know (from testing) that this method, in turn, calls the "set_button_labels" method back in the Schedule class. However the "set_button_labels" method doesn't adjust the text of the SelMealButtons as desired***. Is anybody able to make any suggestions as to why this is and/or how I could achieve this functionality?

I've started reading about slots and signals but having some difficulty getting my head around it.

***(One way around this was to close the Schedule window when the Selector widget is called - and then open it again when the Selector widget closes. However I would prefer to keep the Schedule window open.)

Comment: From what you describe, I believe that you're not using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) (which should *always* be used, as using fixed geometries is generally a *bad* idea), but, in any case, please edit your post and include the `ui` files (most importantly the one used in the Schedule class). Btw, for future reference you should always try to be more succinct and only provide [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): for instance, the whole project description is completely meaningless for the question.

Comment: Links to UI files added.

Comment: I said: "edit your post and **include** the ui files". Code should not be provided using external resources but always embedded in the question, as other websites might become unavailable or the content might be removed (coincidentally, that's exactly your case, as both links report that the file have been deleted).

Comment: Okay. UI files now embedded in post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that everytime you call the `OKbutton` you are creating a new `Schedule` instance and you're setting the button text on *that* instance, not the main one. Also, that instance is never actuall shown (and the same happens in `close_window()`).

What you need to do is to keep track of the current button and connect to the Selector "ok" button in order to correctly update the values. The following is a possible reimplementation of your example:

```
array = ["Meal 1", "Meal 2", "Meal 3"]
days = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"]
# a simple example of meals "array" with the format "day meal"
meal_schedule = ["{} {}".format(d, m) for d in days for m in array]

class Schedule(base_1, form_1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_1,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.SelMealButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.m_b_pressed(0))
        self.SelMealButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.m_b_pressed(1))
        self.SelMealButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.m_b_pressed(2))

        self.selector = Selector()
        self.selector.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set_button_labels)

        self.buttons = (
            self.SelMealButton, 
            self.SelMealButton_2, 
            self.SelMealButton_3
        )

        # example, wednesday
        self.current_day = 2

    def m_b_pressed(self, button_no):
        self.current_meal_button = self.buttons[button_no]
        self.selector.show()

    def set_button_labels(self):
        index = self.selector.listWidget.currentRow() + self.current_day * 3
        meal = meal_schedule[index]
        self.current_meal_button.setText(meal)


class Selector(base_2, form_2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_2, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        for item in array:
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

Note that there are two important issues with your implementation.

1. The Selector window should probably be a *modal* dialog, which blocks interaction with other windows until it's closed: with your current code the user could select a different meal in the Schedule while the Selector is shown, which would make things very confusing. Create a new *dialog* in Designer (one of the two with buttons already defined) and then call it using `exec_`:

```
class Schedule(base_1, form_1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_1,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.SelMealButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.m_b_pressed(0))
        self.SelMealButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.m_b_pressed(1))
        self.SelMealButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.m_b_pressed(2))

        # not needed anymore
        # self.selector = Selector()
        # self.selector.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.set_button_labels)

        self.buttons = (
            self.SelMealButton, 
            self.SelMealButton_2, 
            self.SelMealButton_3
        )
        self.current_day = 2

    def m_b_pressed(self, button_no):
        selector = Selector(self)
        if selector.exec_():
            index = selector.listWidget.currentRow() + self.current_day * 3
            meal = meal_schedule[index]
            self.buttons[button_no].setText(meal)


class Selector(base_2, form_2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_2, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        for item in array:
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)
```

2. Even if it's not related to the issue at hand, using fixed geometries is normally discouraged, and layout managers should always be used instead. One simple reason for this is that I'm able to shrink both windows, and below a certain size the interface becomes unusable.